# How to adjust "Display in render preview" settings in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, customization, settings

Hey it's the curious Juan again,

Can anyone explain why does my render in "Display in render preview" mode look so different from what is shown in the tutorial: https://youtu.be/VFqOkVZp7t0

This is what I see on my screen...

[image]

and this is what the guy sees in his...
[image]

Can I adjust my settings somewhere to get a better render preview quality?

Here is the blender file link: https://pasteall.org/blend/2ef5a0f92257462fbb7dac0883b5519b

Comment: You haven't said what tutorial you're talking about, or supplied a link to it. If you saw my previous comment before I edited it, Blend exchange is now working here.

Comment: @JohnEason noted and updated.

Comment: Tap 'A' twice in Object mode to deselect everything. Does it look right now?

Comment: No sir still the same...

Comment: The other slight problem is that you haven't actually got a camera in your scene! (I'm just looking through the tutorial very quickly and he is talking about it in the animation section near the end of the tutorial. - Hadn't noticed it was missing before I saw that!)

Comment: Difficult to see which part of the tutorial you've got to with the file you've uploaded and I'm not going right through the tutorial to compare settings, but the image I'm seeing is pretty well identical to tthe one you posted from the tutorial so I don't really see how we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for (if not, I'll delete), but I seem to be able to replicate the sample image by disabling Overlays (orange lines), and using either Scene Lights and Scene World (lighting from your setup) in Material Preview mode, or simply view it in Rendered Preview Mode (scene and world lights not necessary as they are enabled by default):

[image: Scene]